# Error: expression must be a modifiable l value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am attempting to multiply each value of an array by an integer, however I am currently encountering the following error: 'expression must be a modifiable lvalue'. The purpose of this code is that, when a button is pressed, the rectangle is enlarged by a scalar factor of 2. How can I resolve this error?

```
void Draw_Rectangle(unsigned int *rectangle1)
{
    // Call draw rectangle function to draw rectangle 1
    GraphicsFunction_drawRectangle (*rectangle1, *(rectangle1 + 1));

}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int rectangleOne[4] = {85, 5, 130, 20};
    // Call function to draw the rectangle in initial position
    Draw_Rectangle(&rectangleOne[0]);

   while(1) {

       if(*(SWITCH_ptr) == 512) {
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            &rectangleOne[i] = rectangleOne[i] * 1.5;
        }
        Draw_Rectangle(&rectangleOne[0]);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`&rectangleOne[i] = rectangleOne[i] * 1.5;` => `rectangleOne[i] = rectangleOne[i] * 1.5;`

`it is enough also to Draw_Rectangle(rectangleOne);` as arrays are passed by pointers

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
&rectangleOne[i] = rectangleOne[i] * 1.5;
```

to:

```
rectangleOne[i] = rectangleOne[i] * 1.5;
```

or even more simply, just:

```
rectangleOne[i] *= 1.5;
```

The problem with the original version is that it was trying to assign to the *address* of the array element, rather than the array element itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I just wanted to overwrite the third and fourth elements of the array rectangleOne, such that rectangleOne = {85, 5, 170, 30} how do I go about doing this? Would I still need to use pointers?

Comment: You could just do `rectangleOne[2] = 170;` and `rectangleOne[3] = 30;`